# Symfony 2 EntityAudit does not generate history/version tables at all

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to use [EntityAudit Bundle](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit) to version specific tables in my database. I installed EntityAudit from [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/simplethings/entity-audit-bundle) using composer, went ahead and registered it in my AppKernel, then I tried to add the specific entities/tables that I want to keep history off in app/config/config.yml. These are entries I added:

```
simple_things_entity_audit:
   audited_entities:
      - src\Fred\EntityBundle\Entity\Name
table_suffix: _history
```

After doing all this, I executed

> $ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

I only saw the EntityAudit's "version" table created, but not "Name_History" or "Name_audit" (without the table_suffix). I have tried adding more entries but no history/version tables get created at all in my database. What am I doing wrong here? I also do have doctrine migrations installed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this was to take "src":

```
simple_things_entity_audit:
audited_entities:
  - Fred\EntityBundle\Entity\Name
table_suffix: _history
```